# How to animate a custom expansion tile widget? [flutter]

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a custom expansion tile widget that works perfectly fine in functionality but I want to animate it. I tried using `AnimatedContainer` but it didn't really work. I want the animation when the tile is expanded or closed. I'm not very familiar with flutter animations so any help in any direction will be appreciated. This is my current code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 196, 196, 196),
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int active = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('App bar')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          CustomExpansionTile(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomExpansionTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomExpansionTile({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomExpansionTile> createState() => _CustomExpansionTileState();
}

class _CustomExpansionTileState extends State<CustomExpansionTile> {
  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        borderRadius: isExpanded
            ? BorderRadius.circular(10)
            : BorderRadius.circular(
                100,
              ),
        border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isExpanded = !isExpanded;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                borderRadius: isExpanded
                    ? const BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      )
                    : BorderRadius.circular(100),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      'Title',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: isExpanded
                                ? FontWeight.w500
                                : FontWeight.normal,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: isExpanded
                          ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                          : Colors.white,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      isExpanded
                          ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up
                          : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (isExpanded)
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10, bottom: 20, right: 10, left: 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context)
                    .primaryColor, // this is important so that GestureDetector takes in the padding in account
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Wrap(
                    spacing: 10,
                    runSpacing: 10,
                    children: const [
                      Text('child 1'),
                      Text('child 2'),
                      Text('child 3'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**And this is the output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- To call an expansion widget with animation, try this example.

```
  bool isExpanded = false;

  onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },

   ExpandedSection(
        expand: isExpanded,
        child: Container(
          padding: vertical(10),
          child: CustomText(
            text: "Description",
            color: hexColor("#10275A"),
            size: 14,
            height: 1.3,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

- Create a class ExpandedSection

```
class ExpandedSection extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool expand;

  const ExpandedSection({this.expand = false, required this.child});

  @override
  ExpandedSectionState createState() => ExpandedSectionState();
}

class ExpandedSectionState extends State<ExpandedSection> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController expandController;
  late Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    prepareAnimations();
    _runExpandCheck();
  }

  ///Setting up the animation
  void prepareAnimations() {
    expandController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600));
    animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: expandController,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
  }

  void _runExpandCheck() {
    if (widget.expand) {
      expandController.forward();
    } else {
      expandController.reverse();
    }
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(ExpandedSection oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _runExpandCheck();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    expandController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizeTransition(axisAlignment: 1.0, sizeFactor: animation, child: widget.child);
  }
}
```